# How to store Global variable in Django view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, global-variables

In **Django views**, is it possible to create a **global / session variable** and assign some value (say, sent through an Ajax call) in a view and make use of it in **another view**?

The scenario I'm trying to implement will be something like:

View **view1** gets some variable data sent thru' Ajax call:

```
def view1(request):
    my_global_value = request.GET.get("data1", '') # Storing data globally
```

Then, the stored variable is used in another view, **view2**:

```
def view2(request):
    my_int_value = my_global_value # Using the global variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable in the views.py (outside of a function) like this preferably using all CAPS

```
GLOBAL_VAR_X = ''    # Global var
```

Then pass the value to be stored to the global like this:

```
def view1(request):
    # Using "global" to declare it in the function where data is being received and to be passed
    global GLOBAL_VAR_X
    GLOBAL_VAR_X = request.GET.get("data1", '') # Storing data globally
```

Then, the stored variable is used in another view

```
def view2(request):
    my_int_value = GLOBAL_VAR_X # Using the data stored in the global variable "GLOBAL_VAR_X"
    print(str(my_int_value))    # Will print the value in the terminal
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`Session`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-object-guidelines) [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-object-guidelines)

Some example from Django:

```
def post_comment(request, new_comment):
    if request.session.get('has_commented', False):
        return HttpResponse("You've already commented.")
    c = comments.Comment(comment=new_comment)
    c.save()
    request.session['has_commented'] = True
    return HttpResponse('Thanks for your comment!')
```

Edit the MIDDLEWARE setting and make sure it contains
`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`

Your `request.session.get("key")` is also accessible in any other view.

Comment: As I have explained in my query, I want to store (assign) some value in a variable in **view1** and then later use the value stored in another view, **view2**.

Comment: Yes, you can also use it in any other **view**

Comment: Django session cannot store non serializable objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sessions`, but you better delete it after you've done with it. Otherwise, it will persist with the session.

```
def index(request):
    task_created = ""
    if 'task_created' in request.session:
        task_created = request.session['task_created']
        del request.session['task_created']
    ...


def create_task(request):
    ...
    request.session['task_created'] = "ok"
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: If I use your example, `create_task` is the function I am storing my variable **task_created** and passing a value `1234` ("`ok`" in your example) to it. Now, will I be able to access the variable's value `1234` in function `index`? Trying to do this I am getting an error: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name`. **What needs to be done?**

Comment: `index` is the name of your path, you should declare it in your `urls.py`: `path('index/', views.index, name='index')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global variable as shown below:

```py
my_global_value = None # Here

def view1(request):
    global my_global_value # Here

    my_global_value = request.GET.get("data1", '')
    # ...

def view2(request):
    global my_global_value # Here

    my_int_value = my_global_value
    # ...
```

Comment: Happened to visit my own query after a long time. The function `view2` need not have the global declaration (i.e. `global my_global_value`) again. Simply `print` the stored data `my_int_value` (to verify it is being returned.